# SparkR : Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package

Tags: r, sparkr

I have the following code that run a custom function 'func' over a list on SparkR.  This works fine running on my location machine, however when I run it on AWS(EMR), its returning message error "Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘nloptr’".  I already installed the package in the instance.  I am not sure how to fix this.  Any help is appreciated.

```
library(nloptr)
library(SparkR)

func <- function(l) {
  ...
  r <- nloptr::neldermead(...)
  ...
  return(r)
}

list <- c(1:10)
sparkR.session()
spark.lapply(list, func)
sparkR.session.stop()
```

Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘nloptr’